# Bound on conditional expectation and conditional probability

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory, extremal-combinatorics

Let $\epsilon_i, \, i=1, \ldots, N$ be random variables which are taking values on $\pm A$ with equal probability and such that $\sum_{i=1}^N\epsilon_i=K$. Let $N=2n=\sum_{i=1}^{2n}n_i, \, n_i \in \{0, \ldots, N\}$.

How to compute or bound

$$
E\left(\prod_i \epsilon_i^{n_i}\right)\leq ?
$$
and 
$$
P\left(\prod_i \epsilon_i^{n_i}=A^{k}\right),
$$
where $k\leq 2n$.

Comment: Just double-checking: (1) Presumably "Let $a \in \mathbb{R}^N$" delares a $N$-vector, but where does it come into play? (2) The statement "$N=2n=\sum_i^{N}n_i$" says $N$ is even, and then the set $\{n_i\}$ is a partition of $N$ into $N$ parts? I suppose each $n_i$ is an integer from zero up to $N$?

Comment: I think there no vector $a$ should be there...

Comment: Thank you. Yes, there is no vector $a$ there and yes, $n_i$ are natural numbers up to $N$ plus zero.